# Intel Built-in e1000e driver broken in 15.04 Vivid Vervet

Tags: networking, intel, nic

It seems (sadly) that the built-in e1000e driver for an Intel Gigabit Ethernet controller does not work in Ubuntu 15.04. I found a workaround by obtaining a USB Gigabit Ethernet Adapter, but I wonder why the current Intel drivers are not available in the kernel?

I had a double-whammy of both the Nvidia grub mode issue (had to set the nomodeset option in Grub) and the e1000e driver not working in 15.04 (no networking), but I managed to get a USB apapter to work and the machine online though not with the onboard ethernet controller.

It made it really hard to have both of these issues occur at once. I've been using Ubuntu since Dapper days and this was the first time two issues hit me at once. it was hard to report anything when you can't see the screen and are off the network at the same time.

I would install the Intel driver, but I want to know if I have to recompile it for every kernel update? If so, I will stick with a working ethernet adapter and be done with the issue.

Have a nice day!

freecode

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact model number of your intel NIC.  If you have installed Synaptic or any other software package manager, be sure you have installed `intel-microcode`.  I had multiple issues with drivers until I updated the microcode package.

Comment: Will do this after work today - need to grab that model with the commands:       lspci -vvv | grep -A 20 Ethernet and modinfo e1000e (reminder to self).

Comment: I have the same problem Hardware:
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
I even installed the latest driver from the intel HP, version: 3.2.4.2-NAPI. With no change at all. As soon as I activate ethernet I am offline. wifi works at least... intel-microcode was missing but didn't help either.

Comment: I never got it to work again, just bought a different NIC (gigabit USB) and that just works. Seems that should be working out of the box with the kernel though, but got tired of being offline.